# Adding Parameters to URLs - AddThis

Tags: php, javascript, addthis

When I like the page from my site, the link is from index...I need that this link be the link of the correct page...I'm trying to take the url address( have the index of my site..then I click in a image..and open another link with infos from my photo. There has a like button and when I click , this like the link of the first page of my site , don't the current page)
I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381249-adding-parameters-to-urls#.UW1-Kit8KPV

here is the code that I have tried:

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .float-all {
        float: left;
        width: 82px;
        height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 4px 2px;
    }
    .post-btn-share {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

</style>

<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="post-btn-share">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
        <div class="float-all">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="float-all">
            <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="float-all">
            <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = {
url_transforms : {
add: {
img: '<?php echo $_GET['img']; ?>',
user: '<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>'
  }
 }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51473a5c09315ac4"></script>

<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through the AddThis support site I found this article regarding URL & Title:
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381242-url-title#.UW26obVg8y4.

> Note: Some services, most notably Facebook and LinkedIn, do not use
>   parameters we send to them. Rather, they use meta tags to determine
>   the URL, title, and description to share. See this blog post for more
>   information. [See this blog post for more information](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2012/09/27/debugging-sharing-to-facebook/#comments).